# Installing extra RAM in Lenovo Ideapad 330, Intel i3 7th gen laptop

Tags: laptop, motherboard, memory, intel

Initially I'm having 4GB of RAM in my Lenovo Ideapad 330 laptop.
Now I want to know if it is possible to add an extra 4GB of RAM to a total of 8 GB of RAM.
If yes, what will it do to the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can upgrade your RAM by replacing the current one as this laptop has single RAM slot, but can't add another extra RAM due to lack of RAM slot.**

`You can check the video I am providing the link below, how to upgrade RAM of your laptop`

[Check this video from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vYAo_JrrSA)

Comment: So, Can i know till how much of RAM is it compatible?@Md.Rejaul Karim

Comment: You can add 16GB of RAM using single RAM Stick

Comment: Thank you! Can you please which type of company RAM does it support for the motherboard in the ideapad?